# How to edit property in JavaScript function class?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have this class based on pure javascript:

```
var DrawFeatureP = /*@__PURE__*/(function (Draw) {
    function DrawFeatureP() {
        debugger
        Draw.call(this, {
            source: new ol.layer.Vector({ source: new ol.source.Vector() }),
            type: 'change this property from function in pottom'
        });

        document.getElementById('lineToggle').onclick = this.handleDrawFeature.bind(this);
     }


    if (Draw) DrawFeatureP.__proto__ = Draw;
    DrawFeatureP.prototype = Object.create(Draw && Draw.prototype);
    DrawFeatureP.prototype.constructor = DrawFeatureP;

    DrawFeatureP.prototype.handleDrawFeature = function handleDraw(evt) {
        //when is function is fired how ca i set 'type' property?
    };

    return DrawFeatureP;
}(ol.interaction.Draw));
```

When this function is fired:

```
   DrawFeatureP.prototype.handleDrawFeature = function handleDraw(evt) {
            //when is function is fired how ca I set 'type' property?
        };
```

I need to change the 'type' property :

```
type: 'change this property from function in the bottom'
```

My question is how to edit type property from handleDraw function?

Comment: In my opinion  this function is impure. because there happens dom manipulation. imho. Change my mind if anyone can

Answer (score 1):

Since you bind `this` when assigning the `onclick` handler, you can use `this.type` in the handler function.

```
    DrawFeatureP.prototype.handleDrawFeature = function handleDraw(evt) {
        this.type = "new type";
    };
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the post. But the example above not works. Any idea what can be the reason?